# Delete all rows coresponding to given ID

Tags: r

Data overview:

```
> str(dataStart[c("gvkey","DEF","FittedRob","NewCol")])
'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  4 variables:
$ gvkey         : int  1004 1004 1004 1004 1004 1021 1021 1021 1021 1033 ...
$ DEF           : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0...
$ FittedRob        : num  0.549 0.532 0.519 0.539 0.531 ...
$ NewCol           : chr  0.549 "Del" 0.519 0.539 "Del2" ...
```

Now, I would like to delete all rows where "Del" or "Del2" occur and thats for given "gvkey".

```
dataStart <- NewDataFrame[ ! NewDataFrame$NewCol %in% c("Del","Del2"),]
```

Where NewDataFrame is the data.frame containing the NewCol. This however deletes only the rows where "Del" and "Del2" occur, I would like to have deleted the whole "gvkey" if either "Del" or "Del2" occur. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first have to select all `gvkey`'s you want to delete:

```
keys_to_delete <- unique(NewDataFrame$gvkey[NewDataFrame$NewCol %in% 
    c("Del","Del2")])
```

And then use these to delete the corresponding rows:

```
dataStart <- NewDataFrame[!(NewDataFrame$gvkey %in% keys_to_delete), ]
```

Comment: hmm, it seems it gives back the deleted entries. I need the other part.

Answer (score 1):

```
set.seed(42)
DF <- data.frame(a = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 10, T), b = sample(1:10, 10, T))
#    a  b
# 1  c  5
# 2  c  8
# 3  a 10
# 4  c  3
# 5  b  5
# 6  b 10
# 7  c 10
# 8  a  2
# 9  b  5
# 10 c  6


library(plyr)
res <- ddply(DF, .(a), transform, test = any(b %in% c(2, 3)))
res[!res$test, 1:2]
#   a  b
# 3 b  5
# 4 b 10
# 5 b  5
```

Comment: Thanks Roland, but on my data it didn't work. In fact I have had similar approach as yours but could not make it work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use a bit of `ave` action, using the example data @Roland used:

```
DF[ave(DF$b,DF$a, FUN=function(x) !any(x %in% c(2,3)))==1,]
```

And an adaptation of Jan's nice answer:

```
DF[!DF$a %in% unique(DF$a[DF$b %in% c(2,3)]) ,]
```

Both giving:

```
  a  b
5 b  5
6 b 10
9 b  5
```

Comment: Thanks. Your second formula works for me. (next time I will submit replicable example for testing!). I'm tempted to accept Jan's answer. Would that be okay? Thanks.